# how do I update an array member when using knockout.viewmodel?

Tags: knockout.js

The knockout.viewmodel plugin includes an option for "arrayChildId" that is used to "identify [the array members] for update purposes", [according to the documentation](http://coderenaissance.github.io/knockout.viewmodel/). However, neither the `pushFromModel` function nor the `updateFromModel` utility function appear to work like that.

I've made an example (below) that shows how those functions actually work -- the former replaces the entire array with the updated element while the former pushes new copies of the updated element on the end of the array, ignoring the `ArrayChildId` property.

What's the correct way to update an array member in a `knockout.viewmodel` view model? If I'm to simply locate the array member myself and update it manually, why is there an `ArrayChildId` option at all?

```js
var model = {
  Crews: [{
    CrewId: 1,
    CrewName: "test 1"
  }, {
    CrewId: 2,
    CrewName: "test 2"
  }]
};

var viewModel = ko.viewmodel.fromModel(model, {
  arrayChildId: {
    "{root}.Crews": "CrewId"
  }
});

viewModel.updateRecord = function() {
  ko.viewmodel.updateFromModel(viewModel, {
    Crews: [{
      CrewId: 1,
      CrewName: "test update 1"
    }]
  })
};
viewModel.updateRecord2 = function() {
  viewModel.Crews.pushFromModel({
    CrewId: 1,
    CrewName: "test update 1"
  })

};


ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="http://coderenaissance.github.com/knockout.viewmodel/knockout.viewmodel.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody data-bind="foreach: Crews">
    <tr>
      <td data-bind="text: CrewId"></td>
      <td data-bind="text: CrewName"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<button data-bind="click: updateRecord">Update Record Using updateFromModel</button>
<button data-bind="click: updateRecord2">Update Record Using pushFromModel</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`updateFromModel` assumes that you received an updated model (i.e. containing everything, not just a delta) and makes delta changes to the viewmodel based on that. In other words, "replaces the entire array" is expected effect for your test case. (In reality the object with ID 1 receives an update in your case, it only looks like a replace.)

Compare below, where I highlight the delta changes to the view, proving that it actually works.

`pushFromModel` is not designed to take into account the `arrayChildId`. It applies the mapping options (extend, apend, etc) and pushes the resulting object onto the target array.

```js
var model = {
  Crews: [
    {CrewId: 1, CrewName: "test 1"},
    {CrewId: 2, CrewName: "test 2"}
  ]
};

var vm = ko.viewmodel.fromModel(model, {
  arrayChildId: {
    "{root}.Crews": "CrewId"
  }
});

vm.updateFromModel = function() {
  ko.viewmodel.updateFromModel(vm, {
    Crews: [
      {CrewId: 1, CrewName: "test 1"},
      {CrewId: 2, CrewName: "test 2 new"},
      {CrewId: 3, CrewName: "test 3"}
    ]
  });
};
vm.pushFromModel = function() {
  vm.Crews.pushFromModel({
    CrewId: 1,
    CrewName: "test update 1"
  });
};
vm.yellowFadeIn = function(element, index, data) {
  var $row = $(element).filter("tr");
  $row.css({ backgroundColor: 'yellow' });
  setTimeout(function () {
    $row.css({ backgroundColor: '' });
  }, 500);
};

ko.bindingHandlers.text.realupdate = ko.bindingHandlers.text.update;
ko.bindingHandlers.text.update = function (element) {
  var $elem = $(element);
  ko.bindingHandlers.text.realupdate.apply(this, arguments);
  $elem.css({color: 'red'});
  setTimeout(function () {
    $elem.css({color: ''});
  }, 500);
};
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="http://coderenaissance.github.com/knockout.viewmodel/knockout.viewmodel.min.js"></script>

<button data-bind="click: updateFromModel">updateFromModel</button>
<button data-bind="click: pushFromModel">pushFromModel</button>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody data-bind="foreach: {data: Crews, afterAdd: yellowFadeIn }">
    <tr>
      <td data-bind="text: CrewId"></td>
      <td data-bind="text: CrewName"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. It would appear, then, that the ArrayChildId property isn't used at all internally; the entire array is simply replaced?

Comment: No, that is exactly not what happens. I think you should really try out the sample I gave. Pay close attention to the various highlighting that is going on.

Comment: Hm. OK. Practically speaking, not really useful functionality, then... In the most common use case, if I'm performing some CRUD against a server, it's going to return just the { added, updated } record, not the entire dataset.

Comment: @GrahamCharles HTTP is a stateless protocol, i.e. if you send "GET xyx", you expect a complete instance of xyz as a response. That's the behavior modeled by the plugin. If you want to update only a part of the viewmodel, then make that part of the viewmodel self-contained. Set up a URL on the server that deals with this part only, give that part its own CRUD methods and let it deal with its own affairs.

Comment: @GrahamCharles You can set up self-contained sub-viewmodels via the "custom" processing option. Positive side-effect would be that the sub-viewmodel now becomes more of a component. It is functionally decoupled from the main viewmodel, you could display it elsewhere on the page, and it's better testable, too.